# My boss directly communicates with my subordinates without going through me

Tags: management

I am employed for the post with wide general authorization. My job on the first place is to build framework for detailed operations so that the process goes smoothly. I  have subordinates who make daily operations and transactions and  I should be responsible for whole process including framework and detailed operations.

Almost from the first day, my direct supervisor manages my subordinates over me. He gives them concrete tasks and they report to him, not even putting me in cc mail. I've  tried indirectly to give some remarks but he said to me that the most important think is that the job is done, no matter who has done it.
I  feel very bad and useless and taken away and I am practically without visible tasks and responsibilities.

On the other hand, it seems that his supervisor who employed me likes me and respects me. He is absent most of the time, but  during rare meetings, I don't have impression that  he would fire me. I am almost ill of being put away by my direct boss. What is the best way to overtake my job position  again?

Comment: It looks like your position is redundant.

Comment: As the Bobs would say: "What would you say you DO here?"

Comment: By "subordinates": do you mean people you actually have hire/fire responsibility for, or do you mean people that you are supposed to assign tasks to and hold reviews for, or do you just mean coworkers who are working on a project you are nominally in charge of?

Comment: Chris, thank you for your time and attention to this matter.I mean there are people that I` am supposed to assign tasks to and hold review for. In the company `s organisational  schema, I` am on the head of department. I assume it gives me the right to manage people and processes in this department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retake your job or you can take what's left of it. Either way, it won't be the easiest discussion to have.

I suggest you use facts and results to retake the job. Show that parts of your deliverables depend on dedicated access to allocated resource (your team). Show your concerns about meeting these targets in a routine one-on-one discussion. When asked why you have such concerns, bring up the fact that your team also has to work on side-tasks issued by him. Say you recognize that these are important but also that you have reviewed the impact these side-tasks have on overall output. You have a choice of whether to take this issue head-on by using words like "why do you keep bypassing my management" and use direct words to question his intentions/plans or you can simply rely on facts to let him accept that output/targets will have to be scaled-down if this work pattern continues. Because leaving things as-is is just planning to fail.

As this might be your first attempt at formally discussing the matter, I would try the latter option. Use facts. Show that you are also driven to "get things done". Propose he shares with you upfront so you can better manage the overall output (and give your 2 cents) since you also issue work/tasks to the team. When your team is confused whose work is more important tell him that, when there's misalignment, nobody wins. Or suggest a realignment of resources. Take a staff or some staff out and place them under him (and move their targets off your performance scorecard and onto his).

Stress nothing is personal to you other than this team (that which includes him) meets its targets or do better.

Comment: Thank you, your answer seems to me  as one easy and professional  way to clear the situation. Personnaly, it occured me also idea to split the staff to his and my team, but I had concerns about my boss` reactions. Now when I` put the problem on the paper and after sharing the problem with others  on this site I feel more ability to undertake necessary  changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot  to Luna and Redza Ali for answering to my question.Comments of bharal, Vietnhy, Joel and  Chris helped me to think of my situation in different light.Also, special thanks to editors who had wilingness and care to improve my post in order to get best answers.

Answer (score 4):

**Talk to your boss, but make it about you, not your subordinates.**

Ask for an informal review or meeting. Rather than asking "Why do you keep bypassing my management?", say "I don't feel like I'm doing much managing at the minute. I know you want the job to get done regardless of by whom, but I feel like I'm not meeting expectations. What tasks would you like me to be doing? Am I on target? Can we set some goals for what I should be achieving, what responsibilities I should have?"

Explain how you feel about your role. By asking these questions, you're showing a willingness to improve yourself and be an asset to the team. If your boss can't think of answers to the question "What should my responsibilities be?", you may indeed be in a slightly useless role, and you might want to polish your CV. If he comes up with something that your subordinates are doing instead of you, say that your subordinates already do this. If you should be doing it, he needs to acknowledge this, and back this up in his actions after the meeting (by not assigning tasks to your subordinates, for example).

Send an email after the meeting with a list of the goals and responsibilities you've agreed on. If nothing was agreed on, give your boss time to think about it before another meeting. Your boss *should be able to assign you tasks*.

If he can't, summarise the lack of agreement in the meeting, again in writing, and escalate if you need to - explain to your boss' boss that he isn't giving you any work at all and is bypassing your management responsibilities.

Comment: yes, this is quite good. it might be that the OP's boss isn't used to having a direct report with subordinates, and doesn't realise what is going on. Or the OP's boss might be power mad and trying to do it all to get some promotion we're not aware of. Either way, this is good advice.

Comment: @bharal: Or it might simply be that the supervisor has no confidence in the OP.  Asking "what tasks would you like me to do?" is a great way to feel this out.

Comment: @ChrisLively yes, that too!

Comment: Luna, your answer is exceptional and I am gratefull that you dealt with my problem . Just for better understanding I would add that my boss should not give a job to me.I know my duties and I know what I`am supposed to do. The problem is that he has in a matter of fact taken  my job`s performing.In reality,due to his attitude, I have neither subordinnees to expect report from nor the boss to report to.I`am  completely pushed away.

Comment: Indeed, and sorry if this wasn't clear in my answer, but I think you should acknowledge both of these points in front of him, as you say you've spoken to him and his response is that it doesn't matter as long as the job is done. If you say "I know what my responsibilities are, but other people seem to be doing them which you seem to be okay with. Are you okay with what I am doing? What should I do instead?" Go with what he says in response, not with your job description, and see.